# Most efficient way to obtain data from a list of objects?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of objects like this (created from PHP then json encoded):

```
{"10":{"10":["4","7","2","2","0","32"],"11":["5","22","1","1","0","0"]}}

translated:

{"X":{"Y":["unique_id","data","data","data","data","data"],"Y":["unique_id","data","data","data","data","data"]
```

But im trying to find a way to obtain the X:Y by looking for the unique_id lets say it was 4.

What would be the most efficient way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're unique ID's, create a separate lookup table.

```
var id_lookup = {};

for(var x in data)
    for(var y in data[x])
        id_lookup[data[x][y][0]] = [x,y]

var coords = id_lookup[4];

alert(coords);  // [10,10]

alert(data[coords[0]][coords[1]]); // ["4","7","2","2","0","32"]
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/LXE3B/

Comment: So in order to reduce load - best to create the look up on pre load then i can search it when i need it ? :)

Comment: @Dave: Yes, you create the lookup table once, then use it thereafter. Or if possible, you could create it on the server side, and send it as a separate JSON structure.

Comment: Hmm ideally would rather the user's PC do the work rather than my server :P hehe

Comment: @Dave: Good point, especially if the structure changes per request. Saves bandwidth too.